# How to understand if Heap is full and why malloc keeps return NULL?

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

As an exercise, currently I am working on a project: a personal text based database (hence a collection of (personal and not) data arranged in a file as a sort of "database") managed with C programming Language.

I thought to keep all the managing function on a `.h` file and the main functions (the one that interact with the user, owner of the database) in a `.c` file.
The `.h` file is not completed yet, but I am slowly testing each function to see if they work correctly.

In particular this one it is daunting me duo to the fact I cannot find the reason why heap gets full (if it really gets full...).

Here is the full code: (The interested function is called "initobj". Though I shared the full code thinking it could be useful to understand)

```
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
    #define PATH "C:\\Database\\"
#elif defined(_WIN64)
    #define PATH "C:\\Database\\"
#elif defined(__linux__)
    #define  PATH "/Database/"
#else
    #define PATH NULL
#endif

struct user{
    unsigned int uid;
    char *username;
    char *password;
};

struct file{
    unsigned int uid;
    char *filename;
    char *content;
};

char *initpath(void){
    char filename[] = "Database.txt";
    char *path = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(PATH) + 1);
    if(path != NULL){
        strcpy(path, PATH);
        mkdir(path);
        strcat(path, filename);
        return path;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}

int initobj(struct user *elem, unsigned uid, char *username, char *password){
    elem->uid = uid;
    if((elem->username = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(username) + 1)) != NULL)
        strcpy(elem->username, username);
    else
        return -1;
    if((elem->password = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(password) + 1)) != NULL)
        strcpy(elem->password, password); //Password is copied into the structure as a normal string. Future updata: encrypting the password
    else
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

int insobj(int database, struct user elem){}

int checkid(int database, unsigned int id){}

int checkusr(int database, char *username){}

int checkpasw(int database, char *password){}
```

Here instead is the main function code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "database.h"

struct user playground;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    srand(time(0));

    int err;
    struct user *p = &playground;
    char *filepath = initpath();

    if(filepath != NULL && argc == 3){
        if((err = initobj(p, (rand() % 999), argv[1], argv[2])) == 0)
            printf("%u, %s, %s <-  Data inserted.\n", p->uid, p->username, p->password);
        else
            printf("[DEBUG]: From function 'initobj' : %d.\n", err);
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Not enought arguments.\n", argv[0]);

}
```

The program keeps return me -1:

```
C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\ACCESS\Database\lib>dat username password
[DEBUG]: From function 'initobj' : -1.
```

Hence means malloc is not able to allocate space in head. I just don't understand why.

Comment: `strcat(path, filename);` You only allocate enough space for `PATH`  but then try to append `filename`.

Comment: Does it work if you change `strlen(PATH)` to `(strlen(PATH) + strlen(Filename))`?

Comment: Most functions set a more specific error code in `errno` when the return value indicates an error. You could use e.g. `perror("malloc (username)")` to display an error message. You wrote "I thought to keep all the managing function on a .h file and the main functions (the one that interact with the user, owner of the database) in a .c file." You seem to misunderstand the purpose of .c and .h files. A .h file should contain declarations only, e.g. function prototypes. The implementation should be in a corresponding .c file. Your program can be compiled from more than one .c file.

Comment: @Bodo Aside: "Most functions set a more specific error code in errno when the return value indicates an error." overstates.  The C lib specifies few functions that set `errno`.  `malloc()` is not specified to set `errno`.  Perhaps you are thinking of some implementation specific behavior?  But since code uses non-standard `mkdir()`, your suggestion does apply more.

Comment: KmerPadreDiPdor, Note that `rand() % 999` results in values [0...998], not [0...999].

Comment: Headers should be reserved for declarations only.  Do not put function bodies in a header file.  It is perfectly fine, however, to split your functions among multiple .c files, in which case you probably want declarations (only) for at least some of them to appear in a header file.

Comment: fyi `strdup` combines malloc and strcpy, makes the code much clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least these issues:

**Code fails to allocate sufficient space** [@
Johnny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71560938/how-to-understand-if-heap-is-full-and-why-malloc-keeps-return-null/71561611#comment126477119_71560938)

```
char filename[] = "Database.txt";
char *path = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(PATH) + 1); // Wrong size & sense
if(path != NULL){
    strcpy(path, PATH);
    mkdir(path);
    strcat(path, filename); // !! Undefined behavior (UB) !!
    return path;
}
```

With the UB of `strcat(path, filename);`, rest of code is irrelevant.

Instead

- Account for both `PATH` and `filename`
- Cast not needed.
- Scaling by `sizeof(char) * strlen(PATH) + 1` should have been `sizeof(char) * (strlen(PATH) + 1)`. `sizeof(char)` is 1 and is not needed either.

  ```
  char filename[] = "Database.txt";
  //                     PATH        filename minus its \0   \0
  char *path = malloc(strlen(PATH) + (sizeof filename - 1) + 1);
  ```

**`mkdir()` may fail**

Better code would test `mkdir()` success.

```
if (mkdir(path)) {
  Handle_failure();
}
```